# How assemble Gradle build under java tasks but compile source under Android SDK

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have build based on java plugin (gradle) tasks. So it has tasks like compileJava, jar, javadoc etc.
But I want to compile sources under Android SDK.
Is it possible to point such rule. It's like I can asemble build under JDK8 but point  target 1.6. Is it possible to configure build to assemble it with java plugin tasks but compile the sources with Android SDK?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you have a pure java project and you want to run it with Android SDK ?

Comment: yes, I have pure Java project build which assembles jar for customer's Java application. Now I want assemble jar for Android app of customer. So I would like to use my current build code but compile sources under Android SDK.